No dags example in Airflow initial installation
I am currently learning Airflow and need the example of DAG to learn. However, after installed and login Airflow, there is no DAG examples  showed in the UI, as per showed in the tutorial. I have checked the load_examples=True which suppose to load the examples. How can I make it load the examples?
Here is the version
apache-airflow==2.10.3
apache-airflow-providers-common-compat==1.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-io==1.4.1
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.17.1
apache-airflow-providers-fab==1.4.0
apache-airflow-providers-ftp==3.11.1
apache-airflow-providers-http==4.13.1
apache-airflow-providers-imap==3.7.0
apache-airflow-providers-smtp==1.8.0
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite==3.9.0

Appreciate if anyone can help.
